# InputStreamReader strange output

Tags: java

So I just began learning Java FileI/O and was playing around with Input Stream Reader. However, the output for an exercise that I did was very strange and also did not match the guide I was following.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws InterruptedException
{
    InputStreamReader cin = null;
    try {
        cin = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        char s = 0;
        while (s != 133) {
            s = (char) cin.read();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File IO Error");
    } finally {
        try {
            cin.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is supposed to just print the character, but it also prints a bunch of line breaks.

```
a
a
<linebreak>
<linebreak>
<linebreak>
```

When I cast the char to an int, it outputs the character id, and then 13 and 10.

```
a
97
13
10
```

Does anyone know what the problem is + how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: 13, 10 represent LF( Line Feed ) and CR ( Carriage Return ), you have LF, CR in your input.

Comment: You should be using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as well. It would make your code less complex and less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

`read()` will read single character, when you press enter it reads carriage return (new line feed) as well and outputs it's representation as well.

Replace

```
System.out.println(s);
```

with

```
System.out.print(s);
```

In general `InputStreamReader` is low level, it is recommended to use wrappers such as `BufferedReader` as follows (it will solve your question as well)

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String tLine = null;
// now reading line of characters (delimited by carriage return)
while ((tLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(tLine);
}
```

Another suggestion is to use `try-with-resources`, instead of traditional try-catch block.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        // your code
}
// Resource will be closed automatically at this line
```

Comment: OP want to print each character on a separate line. That's not the question. The question is about the extra blank lines printed after the two lines with `a`.

Comment: Quote : "The code is supposed to just print the character", I don't see where he mentions about new line.

Comment: OP is asking about the additional `<linebreak>` at the end, which are a result of the `CR` and `LF` characters in the input stream.

Comment: He is also asking how to fix it, my solution does not do that?

Comment: Using `System.out.print(s)` is a good & simple idea, plus one though!

Comment: I guess that entirely depends on what OP expects output to be if he types `ab` before pressing enter. If OP expects `a` and `b` on separate lines, then no, using `print()` is not the answer. The answer would be to ignore `CR` and `LF` in the input stream, though *not* the way [Yahya suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067684/5221149).

Comment: I did not notice OP asking that he wants output in the newline, and indeed my suggestion does output in new line. Thank you for your suggestion, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is asking for input. To provide that input, your press `a` then hit `<enter>`.

That `<enter>` key becomes the character `CR` (decimal 13) and `LF` (decimal 10) in the input stream.

The result is that your program reads 3 characters.

Comment: You did not provide a way to fix it.

Comment: @Yahya Correct. Is was answering the *"Does anyone know what the problem is?"* question, leaving it up to OP to come up with an appropriate fix, now that problem is understood. Guiding people to come up with their own solutions teaches them a lot more than just giving them the solution, with or without explanation.

Comment: This is repeating to the comment by *svasa* and it partially answers the question. This answer gives no extra info to the OP they already got before your answer.

Comment: @Yahya It is not a repeat. It is an expansion of that comment, explaining *why* there are `CR` and `LF` characters in the input stream, not just stating the fact that there are.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is adding:

```
if(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")){cin.skip(2);} // for Windows
else{cin.skip(1);} // for unix-like OS
```

after the `System.out.println(s);` line, in this case your program skips the two chars `Line Feed` and the `Carriage Return` coming from `Enter`.
[image]

Comment: That blindly assumes that user only enters one character before pressing enter. It also assumes Windows, since I don't believe input stream would contain both `CR` and `LF` on Linux.

Comment: @Andreas Re-read the OP question! *The code is supposed to just print the character,* AND *`s = (char) cin.read();  System.out.println(s);`*. Does that seem to ya reading a bunch of chars and displaying them on one line?

Comment: Guys, there is no need to argue this way. Everyone is free to disagree. It is always good to hear other party's opinion and extract something from that. Benefit from disputes.

Comment: @fg78nc I don't mind constructive criticism, but some people admire dodging, for e.g, look at the commenter's claim above, he wants to add assumption to the question that not originally exist. The OP cearly asking about **ONE** char per **LINE** and in Windows Platform.
Constructive Criticism would be recommending to add to code if its core is correct, not just downvoting to pull the attention to his answer! if ya got me.

Comment: I understand, that is communication problem, happens cause people interpret things differently, especially when they are reading. Constructive discussion would help, or just let it go. Life is too short.. :)
P.S. Down vote retaliation is not a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, but where in the question does it say that user is only supposed to enter one character before pressing enter? Sure, the *example* shows that, but question doesn't say that that is a requirement. Your answer would fail terribly, with obscure results, if user enters multiple characters. --- Where in the question does it say that code only runs on Windows? Sure, the *example* shows result that would only happen on Windows, but giving a solution that only works on Windows, and breaks the code if run on Linux, without warnings to that effect, is a bad answer in my book.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println() not only prints out your string but it also advances to a new line. In Java, this is done by using both a carriage return and a line feed. A carriage return has an ASCII value of 13 and a line feed has an ASCII value of 10, which is why you see a 13 and a 10 returning too.

I'm not an expert at Java but I think the reason you are getting three linebreaks is because when you enter a character into the input stream reader, you not only enter the character but you also press the Enter key to input the character. So if you enter the character 'a' and press Enter, then your program will output the character a and then print a linebreak since it's a System.out.println(). It will then output the Enter character, causing another linebreak, and then print a third linebreak (since it's a System.out.println).